# Minimize a trig function. Getting stuck.

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives, optimization, proof-verification

So I have just about given up on this. Here is the problem. FYI, all angles are in degrees, and $L$, $R$ are just strictly positive scalars.

I have a trig-function $D$. Its derivative shown below, is given by:

$$
\frac{\delta D}{\delta \theta} = -LRsin(240-\theta)\big[L^2 + R^2 - 2LRcos(240-\theta) \big]^{-1/2} - LRsin(\theta)\big[L^2 + R^2 - 2LRcos(\theta) \big]^{-1/2}
$$

This derivative function $\frac{\delta D}{\delta \theta}$, when plotted when plotted against $\theta$ looks like this:

[image]

As you can see it's zeros are at $30^{\circ}$ and $-150^{\circ}$.

I am trying to analytically find its zeros, and I start by simply equating the above function to $0$, and solving for $\theta$. This has proved to be weird however.

When all said and done, the simultaneous equations I get that need to be solved are:

$$-sin(240-\theta) = sin(\theta) \\ \text{and} \\ cos(\theta) = cos(240-\theta)$$

I am convinced that those are the proper simultaneous equations to solve, however I cannot seem to solve them properly. I have used the [trig properties](http://www.sosmath.com/trig/Trig5/trig5/trig5.html) of course. My problem is that I get spurious answers, when I know that they should be simply $30^{\circ}$ and $-150^{\circ}$.

What do I do from here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sin\theta=-\sin(240^\circ-\theta)=\sin(\theta-240^\circ)\text{ as }\sin(-x)=-\sin x$$

$$\implies\theta=n180^\circ+(-1)^n(\theta-240^\circ)$$ where $n$ is any integer

When $n$ is even $=2r$(say)  $\displaystyle\implies\theta=2r180^\circ+(\theta-240^\circ)\iff r360^\circ=240^\circ$ which is impossible

When $n$ is odd $=2r+1$(say)  $\displaystyle\implies\theta=(2r+1)180^\circ-(\theta-240^\circ)\iff2\theta=r360^\circ+420^\circ$

$\displaystyle\iff\theta=r180^\circ+210^\circ\  \ \  \ (1)$

$$\cos\theta=\cos(240^\circ-\theta)$$

$$\implies\theta=m360^\circ\pm(240^\circ-\theta)$$ where $m$ is any integer

Taking the '+' sign, $\displaystyle\theta=m360^\circ+(240^\circ-\theta)\iff\theta=n180^\circ+120^\circ$ which does not match with $(1)$

Taking the '-' sign, $\displaystyle\theta=m360^\circ-(240^\circ-\theta)\iff m360^\circ=240^\circ$ which does not match with $(1)$ either

---

Alternatively,

$$\sin x=-\sin A=\sin(-A)\implies x=n180^\circ+(-1)^n(-A)$$

If $n$ is even $=2m$(say)$,x=m360^\circ-A$

If $n$ is odd $=2m+1$(say)$,x=(2m+1)180^\circ+A$

$$\cos x=\cos A\implies x=r360^\circ\pm A$$

Taking '+','-' signs respectively, we get $\displaystyle x=r360^\circ+ A, r360^\circ- A$

So, we need $\displaystyle x=u360^\circ- A$ where $u$ is an integer

Here $\displaystyle x=\theta, A=240^\circ-\theta\implies240^\circ=u360^\circ$ which is impossible as  $u$ is an integer

Comment: Thanks lab, but what propert(ies) are you using to get from the first line to the second?

Comment: @Spacey, its called the general solution of Trigonometric Equations (http://mathsfirst.massey.ac.nz/Trig/TrigGenSol.htm)

Comment: Ok, you say find the common values of $\theta$ - how is that done from the above though? I can equate them but I have a $(-1)^n$, $n$, $m$, etc...how do you find the common values here?

Comment: @Spacey, let me edit

Comment: Thanks lab. Also, I tried to equate both of them right now and solve but I get contradictory answers...

Comment: Lab I am sorry, but I am not clear how we get the correct answers of $30$ and $-150$ form the above.

Comment: @Spacey, $x=30^\circ$ does not satisfy $$\cos\theta=\cos(240^\circ-\theta)$$ and $x=-150^\circ$ does not satisfy the sine equation

Comment: I understand that, but then how come I have the zeros shown in the image? I clearly have zeros at $30$ and $-150$ degrees. All I am trying to do is find the zeros of the equation above... Thanks.

Comment: To recap - I agree with your analysis of the sine/cosine equations. However clearly we have zeros at $30$ and $-150$. Perhaps the setup I have is wrong? Put another way: How would I simply find the zeros of the equation above?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13326/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-spacey)